# Setting up this volume integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I just have a quick question on setting up a volume integral of a region bounded by $y = \sin(x)$ and $y = -\sin(x)$ for $0\leq x\leq\pi$ about the x-axis. I keep getting zero when I set it up as $x = \sin^{-1}(y)$ and similar for the outer radius, but I don't know why. Any help is appreciated, thanks, should just be a small problem.

Comment: do you mean volume (as in revolve a curve around the $x$ axis), or an area?

Comment: Revolving around the $x$-axis, sorry I didn't make that clear. MY first attempt had the area of the integral $V = \pi\int A(y)dy$ look something like $A(y) = (\sin^{-1}(y)-5)^2 - (\sin^{-1}(-y) - 5)^2$, which does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $\arcsin(x)$ have image $y\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, but you are searching for $0\leq x\leq \pi$.

If you take $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, then, we have the radius of the bigger disk (in respect to the line $x=5$) is:
$$5-\arcsin(y)$$

The smaller disk, instead has radius:
$$5-\pi-\arcsin(y)$$

Note that here, I have used $y$ because the disk will have heigth $dy$. So:
$$V=\int_{0}^{1}\pi\left((5-\arcsin(y))^2-(5-\pi+\arcsin(y))^2\right)dy=20\pi-4\pi^2$$

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the $\pi$ factor on the inner radius due to the behavior of $\arcsin(y)$. This actually makes a lot more sense now too... Thanks!